# How can I automatically format html attributes onto individual lines?

Tags: formatting, sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

Is there a setting or plugin in Sublime Text 3 that would allow me to achieve the following automatically?

```
<element attr1="value"
         attr2="value"
         attr3="value">…</element>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a plugin, but you can search for `(?<=\b") +\b` and replace with `\n\t` which results in a formatting close to requested:

```
<element attr1="value"
    attr2="value"
    attr3="value">…</element>
```

Necessary assumptions: 1) your input data was

```
<element attr1="value" attr2="value" attr3="value">…</element>
```

2) your `element` had had 0 indentation.

The regex highlights a sequence of 1 or more spaces between closing quotation marks to the left and a new word beginning to the right. You can also select them all and multi-insert `enter` and the 9 spaces needed in this very example. More cumbersome, restricted to one `element` at a time, but pretty.

If you expect any quotation marks outside of `element`s, you can use a more robust regex: `(?<=\b") +\b(?=[^<]+>)`. It adds the condition that on the right you can find a closing angle bracket with no opening bracket before it.